# No Store instance for Aeson object

Tags: haskell, aeson, template-haskell

The code below generates orphan instances for `store`. It works fine for `aeson 1.4.7.1` but generates error in `aeson 2.0.3.0`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable,DeriveGeneric,TemplateHaskell,GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,        OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}

import           Data.Store      (Store)
import           TH.Derive
import           Data.Scientific
import           Data.Aeson (Value)

-- This will allow us to serialize Aeson objects
$($(derive [d| instance Deriving (Store (Scientific)) |]))
$($(derive [d| instance Deriving (Store (Value)) |])) -- Template haskell derivation of Store    instance for Value
```

With `aeson 2.0.3.0` (as listed in stackage `LTS-20.13` - working code was compiled using `LTS-16.31` with `store 0.7.1` and `aeson 1.4.7.1`), it now throws errors about some store instance missing for aeson internal object - top level error below:

```
No instance for (Store
                         aeson-2.0.3.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Object)
        arising from a use of ‘store-0.7.16:Data.Store.Impl.size’
```

Will appreciate pointers on how to fix this.

### Update

Added the following template haskell derivations (along with `ScopedTypeVariable` pragma to compile) following suggestions of @daniel-wagner:

```
$($(derive [d| instance Deriving (Store (Key)) |])) 
$($(derive [d|
    instance Store a => Deriving (Store (KeyMap a))
    |]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `Object` (which isn't actually an internal-only data structure; it's also exported from `Data.Aeson.Types` with no `.Internal`) has changed from being a type alias for `HashMap` (which has a `Store` instance) to being [an abstract data structure](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.1.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-KeyMap.html#t:KeyMap) (that does not have an instance). You'll need to write `Store` instances for the `Key` and `KeyMap` types, then you can be on your way. You might, for example, use `toList` and `fromList` for a programmer-cheap implementation for `KeyMap`:

```
instance Store v => Store (KeyMap v) where
    size = contramap toList size
    poke = contramap toList poke
    peek = fmap fromList peek
```

And similarly `toText` and `fromText` for `Key`:

```
instance Store Key where
    size = contramap toText size
    poke = contramap toText poke
    peek = fmap fromText peek
```

If you are writing a library, you might want to shove these instances into their own package that is somehow easily discoverable on Hackage -- say, by naming it `store-aeson` or something -- to reduce the pain of orphan instances. If you're just writing an application, you're probably fine. (I dream of there one day being a searchable orphan instance registry... one of these days, in my copious free time...)